# How to use boost::shared_ptr/std::shared_ptr with boost::object_pool?

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, pool

1. Should I ever prevent memory leaks using shared pointers with boost::object_pool (in case of an exception inside malloc-destroy block)?
2. If yes, what is the correct way to initialize shared_ptr?
3. How to clean up memory afterwards?

```
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::object_pool<int> pool;
    // Which is the correct way of initializing the shared pointer:

    // 1)
    int *i = pool.malloc();
    boost::shared_ptr<int> sh(i);
    int *j = pool.construct(2);
    boost::shared_ptr<int> sh2(j);

    // or 2)
    boost::shared_ptr<int> sh(pool.malloc());

    // Now, how should i clean up the memory?
    // without shared_ptr I'd call here pool.destroy(i) and pool.destroy(j)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be a shared pointer?

`unique_ptr` has the benefit to encode the deleter into the type:

```
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>

template <typename T, typename Pool = boost::object_pool<T> >
struct pool_deleter {
    pool_deleter(Pool& pool) : _pool(pool) {}
    void operator()(T*p) const { _pool.destroy(p); }
  private:
    Pool& _pool;
};

#include <memory>

template <typename T> using pool_ptr 
    = std::unique_ptr<T, pool_deleter<T, boost::object_pool<T> > >;

int main() {
    boost::object_pool<int> pool;
    pool_ptr<int> i(pool.construct(42), pool);

    std::cout << *i << '\n';
}
```